# Allocate NSInteger*

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I'd like to create an instance of a NSInteger pointer in Objective C.

```
-(NSInteger*) getIntegerPointer{
  NSInteger  refValue = 0;
  NSInteger* theReturn = &refValue;
  return theReturn;
}
```

When I call this function `theReturn` is nil, but is valid within the function with the debugger.

Any suggestions? I do not want to change `theReturn` to NSInteger.

Comment: It's not legal to return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Why do you want to use pointers? `NSInteger` isn't a class. You don't have  instances. It's a simple primitive type.

Comment: Maintain a global variable. This code seems pointless.

Comment: You are right the code is pointless, it is just a snipplet.  There are some other functions that require a NSInteger*, that I want to initialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `refValue` is a local variable, which means that it will be on the stack while the `-getIntegerPointer` method is executing. As soon as that method returns, the variable will go away (be popped off the stack), so it's address is no longer meaningful.

If you want to return a valid pointer, you have to allocate the memory for the thing being pointed to, like this:

```
-(NSInteger*) getIntegerPointer{
    NSInteger  refValue = 0;
    NSInteger* theReturn = malloc (sizeof(NSInteger));
    *theReturn = refValue;
    return theReturn;
}
```

Comment: and you will leak memory

Comment: Well that depends on what the caller does with the memory. Presumably, it will be used and then freed when appropriate. But that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Thank you and your are correct this is beyond the scope of the question but if I did this would it release it correctly:
    NSInteger* temp = [self getIntegerPointer];
    // Do things
    free(temp);